# no "go to definition" and no function definition pop-up for golang code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code to code in golang.

For this particular code example: https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/, I can't see any function definition pop-up, nor can I use "go to definition" in vscode by pressing F12. I can see the definition pop-up in other projects on my computer.

I have set my gopath in .bashrc in ubuntu 16.04 using the env.sh

All the plugin and visual studio code versions are the latest. What should I do to use the function definition prompt?

update: the problem is now solved by setting:

```
export GOPATH=`pwd`
```

instead of:

```
export GOPATH=${GOPATH}:`pwd`
```

Comment: I cloned that repo and it works for me. Are there any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: strange to me. Can you use the vscode to "go to definition" (F12) for some function inside the file?

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. The problem is now solved.

Comment: I still have no idea how to have multiple gopath working. Is that doable in vscode for go? I want to keep the "go to definition" (F12) working when openning multiple projects.

Comment: What about windows I can never "go to definition" ?

Answer (score 16):

This issue is in new versions or updates of vs code. My version is `1.22`, It started working in my vs code when I tried to edit the settings of go extension for Go doc tool in

```
File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Go(Configuration)
```

Set Docs Tool from `godoc` to `gogetdoc`. If you have not downloaded `gogetdoc`. Download it first and restart vscode for it to load the tool.

```
go get -u github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc
```

Now Press `F12` to go to definition. I hope it helps.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Downloading the `gogetdoc` worked for me after running `go mod tidy`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close `go:use` the language server, `go:docs` tools will not be applicable when you use language server.

Language server works fine for most of the code stuffs, but you cannot go to definition of some functions in third-party packages.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else I am also adding an issue I faced and resolved that caused the same problem:

- Issue: go to definition not working
- go.mod file was red(highlighted by VsCode) which meant that a module was not installed successfully
- I found the module (X) and installed it manually go get X
- Restarted VsCode

This resolved the issue with the go to definition functionality

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just run `go mod tidy`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue due to inconsistent vendoring. So, I executed the following commands and was good to go.

```
go mod vendor
go mod tidy
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled go extension for vs code. And the VS code popped up notification to install it again. After installing extension, another notification popped up to install tools for go. After installing it everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. It turned out that asdf was to blame. A .tools-versions file was specifying a version that I didn't have. Go then failed to load and VS Code had no Code awareness.